# How to register an HttpFilter?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I've created an **HttpFilter** in my project:

**ExampleFilter.java**

```
package contoso.grobber;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebFilter("")
public class ExampleFilter extends HttpFilter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) 
    {
        beginRequest(req); //before request processing
        chain.doFilter(req, res);//calls other filters and processes request
        endRequest(req, res); //after request processing you can use res here
    }

    private void beginRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
       //...
    }

    private void endRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
       //...
    }
}
```

But the filter just isn't being called.

Supposedly using the `@WebFilter` annotation is enough to make it work:

- but [it's not documented as a way to register a filter](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpFilter.html)
- and people can't make it work <sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426872/servlet-filter-not-working) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687127/java-servlet-filter-not-working-on-login) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856866/using-tomcat-webfilter-doesnt-work-with-filter-mapping-inside-web-xml) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11795084/filter-not-working) [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670158/filters-not-working-properly)</sup>

What's the alternative?

I've [heard tell of modifying `web.xml` to register the filter](https://www.guru99.com/jsp-filter.html); but that is for a **Filter**s - and not an **HttpFilter**s.

Day 12 of trying to get this to work...:

- [How to hook BeginRequest and EndRequest in JavaEE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72995407/how-to-hook-beginrequest-and-endrequest-in-javaee)
- [How to hook begin and end of HTTP requests in JavaEE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73213473/how-to-hook-begin-and-end-of-http-requests-in-javaee)

Comment: I can confirm that `@WebFilter` can be used to annotate and trigger your `ExampleFilter` extending `HttpFilter` - but I am using `@WebFilter("/*")` (all traffic) not `@WebFilter("")`. It also works for specific routes such as `@WebFilter("/demo_one")` and so on. Furthermore, I am using Jakarta (`jakarta.jakartaee-web-api`) v9.1.0 and not Javax. Your question is tagged "Jakarta" but you are using `javax` in your code. I am using Tomcat 10, and I do not have a `web.xml` file - only annotations such as `@WebServlet`. I don't know how that may or may not help you, but I wanted to share the basics.

Comment: If it helps I can share more - for example, the steps I took to set up my Tomcat app - but there are no guarantees that would help you, given you may have a very different starting point from me.

Comment: @andrewJames Oh is **that** was the string in the parenthesis is for! It would have been absolutely ***SUPER*** if that was mentioned in the [documentation of @WebFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebFilter.html)! Just super! That did it - [the original answer i was going from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73213473/how-to-hook-begin-and-end-of-http-requests-in-javaee/73213666?noredirect=1#comment129303992_73213666) didn't mention that - and left it blank.  So i left it blank too; i dunno what it meant.

Comment: Ah - the `""` string means "the application’s context root" - so it's possible you were never hitting that - and therefore never seeing your filter being called. More notes in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Converting the relevant parts of my comments to an answer here:*

---

**Short Answer**

You need to provide one or more values in the string of the `@WebFilter` annotation, to represent the URL pattern(s) to which the filter applies.

So, for example, the following refers to all URLs under the root of your app:

```
@WebFilter("/*")
```

And the following refers to one specific URL:

```
@WebFilter("/demo_one")
```

---

**Longer Answer**

The `@WebFilter` annotation is part of the Jakarta Servlet specification. For example, here is the Web Filter section for [version 5.0](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/jakarta-servlet-spec-5.0.html#_WebFilter) of the spec.

The empty string used in `@WebFilter("")` is a special pattern, documented [here](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/jakarta-servlet-spec-5.0.html#specification-of-mappings):

> The empty string `("")` is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to the application’s context root, i.e., requests of the form `http://host:port/<context-root>/`. In this case the path info is `"/"` and the servlet path and context path is the empty string (`""`).

Other rules for URL patterns are also covered here, including wildcards (`*`).

---

The [JavaDoc for `@WebFilter`](https://tomee.apache.org/jakartaee-10.0/javadoc/jakarta/servlet/annotation/WebFilter.html) lists all of the attributes you can use in the annotation.

(*As you note, the JavaDoc does not make it especially clear which of these attributes is mandatory, or explain how they work in any detail.*)

One of these attributes is `value` - an array of strings:

> The URL patterns to which the filter applies. The default value is an empty array.

So, instead of `@WebFilter("/demo_one")` you can use:

```
@WebFilter(value = "/demo_one")
```

Or, for an array of URL patterns:

```
@WebFilter(value = {"/demo_one", "/demo_two"})
```

If you don't use the `value =` specifier (i.e. if you *only* use a string and nothing else), then the annotation assumes the provided string is the one provided mandatory value (one of `urlPatterns`, `servletNames`, or `value`).

You can see there is a fairly long list of other attributes you can specify in the annotation - they are all the equivalents of the values that you can assign in the XML of a `web.xml` file, if you use that instead of annotations.